# Solve IE7 bug "input type=file" onchange fire twice?

Tags: jquery, events, input, internet-explorer-7, onchange

Did you ever face this IE7's bug:

```
<input type="file" id="xxx">

<script> 
     $('#xxx').change(function(){ alert(1) })
</script>
```

when I click the input & pick a file, the alertbox shows the first time. Then I click on the blank area on the body, the alertbox shows once again. This happens even when I bind the change event to input:file with JQuery 1.6 (lastest at this moment).

How could I prevent this by the simplest way? Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: I think in IE7 the first event is the file changing, the second event is happening when the field loses focus (onblur).

Comment: i'd hate to suggest a variable to limit the code to executing only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I've made after some hard hours of "brain storming" :

```
$('input:file').click(
    function(){
         $(this).one(
              'change',
              function(){ alert(1) /*do stuff here*/ }
         )
    }
)
```

Each time user click the input to choose file, we bind the event "change" one time with it. So the event fires exactly once everytime user want to pick a file.

And thanks god it works ! Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks so much! Wish I could upvote it dozens of times. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply unbind the trigger once your function has ran

Comment: And kill the function for the duration of the page visit after the first run? ;)

Comment: You're right, it could be possible then to put the event on a .blur() trigger for testing purposes to see it if gets called twice, IE might send two instructions to the .change() where .blur() is when you lose focus