# IE11 fires on change event on a text box twice when resetting it's value programmatically

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a form which allows the user to select a file like so:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtUploadFile">Import file</label>
        <input type="file" name="UploadFile" id="txtUploadFile" accept=".csv" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the handler attached:

```
$("#txtUploadFile").on("change", function (e) {
    var fileUploadInput = $(e.target);
    var files = e.target.files;
    console.log("files.length: " + files.length);
    if (files.length === 1) {
        // do the processing here
    }
    else{
        // Show an error asking the user to select a file.
    }
}
```

In IE11 after choosing a file it goes to the else part and end's up showing the error!!!
The console prints twice, once with a value of 1 and then with 0.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmeurs/2rEzF/) shows it.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added, not mine but shows what I am asking about.

Comment: this bug has existed for years. i remember the same issue with IE8 for XP! ofc, sending bug reports to microsoft is impossible, short of kidnapping a dev

Comment: Dont know if it is the same error as seen long time ago on IE7, but the solution back then is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419560/solve-ie7-bug-input-type-file-onchange-fire-twice

Comment: I have that now, Was wondering if it was fixed in IE11, seems not. Thanks anyway.